# Is stereoscopy (3D) in Fez's New Game++ used in any of the puzzles?

Tags: fez

Gomez gets 3D glasses in the New Game++ intro (activated in the settings menu thereafter). Does it reveal any hidden codes, information, or new functions in the levels, or is it strictly just for aesthetics/fun like an Easter egg?

[image: 3D GLASSES]

Comment: I don't know if it's needed for anything, but I noticed a difference in the one room that normally has very limited vision (the one with blinking pink platforms), you can now see everything. Also the room with all the symbols and characters (the epileptic room) appears a bit different. I wanted to check the "gameboy" rooms but didn't remember where they were.

Comment: I'm pretty sure something is hidden somewhere, only visible with the stereoscopic view... It could be the solution for the black monolith.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Nope**—just a fun Easter egg that makes everything 3D.

Comment: You don't know that DeanDMX. Try it out, as of now the use of stereoscopic 3D hasn't been confirmed to hold secrets but I'll bet there are some. The puzzles are so intricate that it's taken a collective effort to figure some out, so it's not out of the question that anything like that is a no-go. Try it out, see if anything reveals itself. Who knows, there might even be extra scenes in the game if you play through it in 3D.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the telescope room. The books below the telescope seem to be a 3D picture. Just guessing, as I have not earned my glasses yet. But clearly, something is there.